# Get the average price for product collection

Tags: magento2, collection, product-collection, orm

If there's a way in Magento 2 to get the average price for a product collection.

Or should I loop over the collection?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would do a loop through each of the products, have a count and a sum and then work out the average.

When your looping through your products remember to have a second loop to check if it is a configurable too to make sure you don't skip the simples.

something maybe like this :

```
$count = 0;
                $sum = 0;
                foreach ($configurableCollection as $product) {

                    $parentProductId = $product->getId();

                    if($product->getTypeId() == \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable::TYPE_CODE) {
                        $_children = $product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($product);

                        foreach ($_children as $child) {
                            $productPrice = $child->getPrice();
                            $sum = ($sum + $productPrice);
                        }
                        
                    } else {
                        $productPrice = $product->getPrice();
                        $sum = ($sum + $productPrice);
                    }

                    $count++;

                }

                $average = ($sum / $count);
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what is the use of $parentProductId = $product->getId();?

Comment: In Magento 2.4.2, it shows all configurable child production in the main loop, so I don't think we need two loops here, just skip the configurable.

Comment: @AboElnouR it is to go through the simple products of the configurables, if your over 2.4.2 then maybe your simple products are already in the main loop. I would put a logger in the loop so you can see exactly whats in your product collection :

$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/logger.log');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info($product->getName());

Comment: @AboElnouR it is to go through the simple products of the configurables, if your over 2.4.2 then maybe your simple products are already in the main loop. I would put a logger in the loop so you can see exactly whats in your product collection :

$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/logger.log');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info($product->getName());